# Domain redirect in Wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, redirect, htaccess

I have two domains `www.domain1.com` and `www.domain2.com`, both pointing to the same host. What I want to do is redirect `www.domain2.com` to `www.domain1.com/domain2`.

I got this code for a .`htaccess` from the hosting provider but is giving me a error "500 Internal Server Error" when I install it. What is the problem?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ [www.] domain1.com $ [NC]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI}! ^ / domain2 / .*
^(.*) RewriteRule / index / $ 1 [L]
```

Comment: This looks like a server configuration issue to me. Please consider using http://serverfault.com/ or another community to ask the question as it is not specific to wordpress.

Comment: for starters remove the spaces in your .htaccess lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `What I want to do is redirect www.domain2.com to www.domain1.com/domain2.`

Then you don't want to do it via `htaccess`. You need to use the [**WordPress MU Domain Mapping**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin.

> Map any blog/site on a WordPressMU or WordPress 3.X network to an external domain.

---

Also see: [**WordPress 3.0: Multisite Domain Mapping Tutorial**](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/)

> The other day, Klint Finley wrote a [very good walkthrough](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/06/02/wordpress-3-multisite/) of using the new Multisite functionality of WordPress 3.0. In the comments, a lot of people wanted to know how to use your own domain names. Since I’m doing that now, here’s a quick walkthrough/how-to guide.

Comment: What i was doing  "blog1.sitename.com -> blog1/" will give 500 error, "blog1.sitename.com -> /" point it to root dir

Answer (score 2):

When you get a "500 Internal Server Error" look into the error log of your webserver. There you will find more information what went wrong.

In your case it's most probably a syntax issue with `.htaccess` directives you wrote. They don't look properly written to me.

For information about `mod_rewrite` please see [Module mod_rewrite URL Rewriting Engine (Apache HTTP Server)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html). There you will find how to write each command, how they work, description of parameters etc.

For more information about the error log, please see [Log Files / Error Log (Apache HTTP Server)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#errorlog). It contains valuable information what you wrote wrong in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks for the information hakre. This code was sent to me from the host and is supposed to work that's why I came here looking for a quick answer. But I'll have a look into that information . Thanks.

Comment: @Pedro Reis: If the host sended that to you, and you made not error applying it, I would contact them and tell them about the problems you have with it.