# Multisite non-www domain redirects to sign-up

Tags: multisite, redirect

I have Multisite enabled and can only view my site with the `www`. When I try without the `www` it sends me to the sign-up page and says

> Registration has been disabled.

```
www.domain.com/portfolio  <-- load correctly
domain.com/portfolio      <-- redirects to sign-up page
```

I've tried `NOBLOGREDIRECT`, but nothing changes.

```
define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.domain.com');
```

In .htaccess, I've also tried the following with no success.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How do I get my site viewable with and without the "www." in the domain?

Comment: what's on your Settings -> General Settins for:
-> WordPress address (URL)
-> Site address (URL)

check that you don't have www in those two urls

Comment: @Azizur that option doesn't appear in 3.1.2 multisite.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:
[Domain redirect in Wordpress multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5874/domain-redirect-in-wordpress-multisite).

You need to use the domain mapping plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

A must read http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/

Comment: +1, I'm using the domain mapping plugin with subdomain install and the OP's RewriteRule in my apache virtualhost conf.

Answer (score 1):

@jaysonp, you were really close but in your Rewrite rule you forgot the www.

Add this in your htaccess file right under RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was in the end very simple: within the Domain Mapping plugin referenced by Azizur's answer above, I added a **new domain without the www** and the same site ID as the www version. I unchecked primary. The result is two entries for the same site (in my case site ID 2), as follows:

```
ID: 2
Domain: www.domain.com
Primary: Yes

ID: 2
Domain: domain.com
Primary: No
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any codes in htaccess file. There is very easy solution to this. In the 'Network Admin -> Settings -> Domains' page, add both the www. and non-www. versions of the domain, select the box of 'primary' for if you want to mainly use for www. or non-www. and both will be assigned to the website.

Comment: I can't find a "Domains" area in the network admin, are you sure that's the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the fix is very simple. In your Network>Sites list make sure you do not use www. for your subsites' url address. Simply configure each of your subsite url subsite.com instead of www.subsite.com.