# How do I map a subdomain in wordpress to the primary domain in a multisite setup?

Tags: redirect, ssl

We have a multisite setup, the primary domain needs to have domain.com, www.domain.com and secure.domain.com mapped in wordpress so the primary site's content loads on them.  The problem we are facing is everything except secure.domain.com works.  secure.domain.com always ends up at: http://www.domain.com/wp-signup.php?new=secure.domain.com

The headers returned from the server are as follows:

Status: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date:   Tue, 16 Oct 2012 19:55:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Location:   http://www.domain.net/wp-signup.php?new=secure.domain.net
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: What domain mapping solution are you using? i.e. which plugin, if any?

Comment: Seems you have the same issue as this poster: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14383/multisite-non-www-domain-redirects-to-sign-up  Had you seen that question?  Did the proposed solution not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just added the following to .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.domain\.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.net/$1 [P,L]
```

This appears to be working fine, but I'm not sure of what types of unforeseen effects it may have if any.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have to have secure.domain.com function or can it redirect?

The tl;dr is that you don't. The primary domain is the cheese: it stands alone. However.... You **can** use .htaccess to check 'If someone is coming from secure.domain.com, send them to domain.com'

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That's about as good as it gets. (Mind you, if your server itself doesn't redirect www.domain.com to domain.com, it needs a kick in the pants anyway...)

Comment: Well, I can't redirect otherwise it would break the SSL connection.  The user must remain on secure.domain.com for certain parts of the site that require a secure connection.

Comment: What are you using secure.domain.com for then?

Comment: secure.domain.com (https) is used for forms/applications.  The rest of the site is http.

Comment: Wait... so secure just isn't supposed to be a part of WP at all? They're separate? If so, you should be able to adjust your vhosts so that subdomain is higher up and kicks in before it picks up wildcards. I have a few named subdomains AND wildcards going on, and they never bump uglies.